# Returning a single recordset from a looping stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I'm not a huge fan of putting queries in a loop, however I need to run a query that loops and executes a stored procedure.

What I have already, works, however the results are being returned in separate result sets, in the manner that is usual with multiple queries being run one after the other.

I need all of the results in a single result set, in the same manner that a UNION would give me.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
declare @id int
--declare @field2 int
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for

-- Build examples to loop through
SELECT 1 AS id
UNION
SELECT 2  AS id
UNION
SELECT 3  AS id

open cur

fetch next from cur into @id

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    --execute your stored procedure on each row
    SELECT @id

    fetch next from cur into @id
END

close cur
deallocate cur
```

This will return the following:

```
-----------
1
(1 row(s) affected)
-----------
2
(1 row(s) affected)
-----------
3
(1 row(s) affected)
```

However I need:

```
id
-----------
1
2
3

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: You can create a #temptable before the loop, then do `INSERT INTO #temptable SELECT @id`, then after the loop `SELECT * FROM #temptable`.

Comment: Can you change the stored procedure so that it receives a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) instead of scalar values? You would not only make your code simpler you would get better performance.

Comment: You may have vastly oversimplified your problem. The first question to ponder is what your "interior" stored procedure produces as output. Does it generate s single resultset? multiple resultsets? output variables? printed message? Or does it not produce any output making your question moot at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put your results into a #Temp table?

Add a temp table to your routine

```
Create Table #tbl
(
id Int
)
```

Your routine

```
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
declare @id int
--declare @field2 int
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for

-- Build examples to loop through
SELECT 1 AS id
UNION
SELECT 2  AS id
UNION
SELECT 3  AS id

open cur

fetch next from cur into @id

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    --execute your stored procedure on each row
    Insert Into #Tbl SELECT @id --ON EACH LOOP, INSERT ID to TEMP TABLE

    fetch next from cur into @id
END

Select * From #Tbl --Present the results of the TEMP TABLE

close cur
deallocate cur
Drop Table #tbl  --Drop your TEMP TABLE
```

Results:

```
id
1
2
3
```

Comment: That's how I'd go with it, although I'd probably go with a table var instead, depending on the size of the data and the number of rows we're talking about.